# MATLAB: replicating value changes to uint8 saved as jpg

Tags: matlab, jpeg, uint8t

I have a bunch of code that I wrote to operate on a series of jpeg images written from a series of uint8s. I'm now trying to run the code on the uint8s and its not working nearly as well (unless I have it open each uint8, imwrite() as a jpeg, and then imread('##.jpg') and perform the code on that). This writing and reading is adding a bunch of time to processing, is there a way to replicate the changes made to the uint8 when its saved as a jpg...without having to save and open?

Thanks

Comment: See: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: jpeg compression is lossy. On top of quantizing the pixels you are also losing other information every time you save. If you just want to replicate the just quantization effects then you could use `img_quantized = uint8(img*255);`

Comment: According to this discussion on the [MATLAB Central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/283892) there doesn't seem to be a way to write to memory in MATLAB. It could theoretically be done by building a wrapper for libjpeg.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but [RAMDisk](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk/) is a free tool which allows you to treat a chunk of RAM as disk space. You could write the files there which should be much faster.